# How to make this Layout in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I an new in Crystal report.How can i make this type of layout in my crystal report

[image: Transcript layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a test object Suppress(`recordnumber <> 6`). Place it along with slno, name, grade etc.
2. Do the same thing with a vertical and horizontal line.
3. For the GPA, Suppress(`recordnumber <> 3`)

Comment: I can't set vertical line.How i set the vertical line?

Comment: Simple click on Insert line. Then pencil symbol will come create a vertical line in detail section..